# PCA: how to make equation from pcrcomp?

Tags: r, pca

Example:

```
#loading data
data(iris)

#PCA
ir.pca <- prcomp(iris[,1:4],scale=T,center=F)

#date frame to check
dt <- data.frame(1,0,0,0)
names(dt) <- names(iris[,1:4])

#prediction how it is computed?
predict(ir.pca,dt)

#things of PCA
ir.pca$rotation
ir.pca$center
ir.pca$scale
```

if the center is FALSE then equation is obvious:

```
predict(ir.pca,dt)[1] == ir.pca$rotation[1,1]/ir.pca$scale[1]
```

but what then the center is TRUE? then I have no idea how to write a formula using the center, rotation and scale.

Comment: centre means whether the variables should be shifted to be zero centered. Alternately, a vector of length equal the number of columns of x can be supplied. The value is passed to scale. Therefore, I think the formula won't change but when you use Center=True , you are making your data scaled around zero. So, what exactly you want to do with PCA? you better ask the question in cross validated and not here

Comment: I just want to get the mathemacial formula (equation) of the PCA result to use it in SQL on new data. In other words I want to be able to compute the PCA component on the paper while having a results of prcomp.

Answer (score 0):

I know that's an old question, and this won´t be a definitive answer, but I hope that it´s enough to direct future viewers to the right direction).

The pseudocode below is only for the 1st principal component, and one row of data, but you can generalize for others:

let rotation_pca1, scale_vec and center_vec be vectors of size N, where N is the number of variables used to calculate the PCA:

```
 rotation_pca1 = ir.pca$rotation[, 1] # Will change deppending on the component.
 scale_vec = ir.pca$scale # Will be the same for all the Principal Components
 center_vec = ir.pca$center # Will be the same for all the Principal Components
```

And let example_row be one vector that represents one row from the data.frame.

```
  pca_variable = rownames(ir.pca$rotation)
  example_row = df[1, pca_variables]
```

What you want to do is, for each row:

```
  escaled_values = (example_row - center_vec) / scale_vec
  pca_value = rotation_pca1 %*% t(escaled_value)
```

Note that `%*%` is the dot product of rotation_pca1 by the escaled_values.
example_row - center_vec is an element by element subtraction
(example_row - center_vec) / scale_vec is an element by element division.

In procedural code:

```
for row in dataframe
   pca_value = 0
   for col in row:
       col_value = dataframe[row][col]
       pca_value = pca_value + rotation_pca1[col]*(( col_value - center_vec[col])/scale_vec[col])
   dataframe[row]["PCA"] = pca_value
```